# trace path in a map in python

Tags: python, maps, openstreetmap

```
orig = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(graph, X=-84.21232, Y=10.01565)
dest = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(graph, X=-84.14267, Y=10.02321)
route = ox.shortest_path(graph, orig, dest, weight='length', cpus=1)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_route(graph, route, route_color='r', route_linewidth=6, route_alpha=0.5, orig_dest_size=100, ax=None)
```

I have this code that finds the shortest route and traces a route on the map, how can I do so that more than one destination can be added to this code? That it passes through the closest point and then to the next, and to the next

I was thinking of making an array, but I don't know how to make it work on this problem

Comment: What is "ox"? Please tell us at least which python module you are using.